# Set localhost name to custom name inside for local wordpress setup

Tags: php, wordpress, localhost, lamp

I want to put a live wordpress site in my local environment, let's say for example the site url is www.test.com , this opens the page, so when I normally set up a local environment in /var/www/html (using lamp btw) i create a directory let's say test (/var/www/html/test) and update in the database the siteurl and home links to http://localhost/test

So when I write in the browser http://localhost/test it will open....but I want to change the hostname and url directy, I want to have in my local environment something like http://local.test.com

Comment: Try reading [the WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) Or google it for lots of options/advise

Comment: @RiggsFolly am not sure if its actually a wordpress specific issue but maybe .httaccess or not

Comment: Then you need to do a bit of research on Apache Virtual Hosts

Comment: Yes, realized it might be that, thanks!

Comment: [This may help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23990618/2310830) but its based on Windows. However the principles are the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is simplest way to convert your localhost to a domain name
if you are on windows follow this steps;
1- goto C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc  (C:\windows is your windows installation folder)
2- seek on a file called "**hosts**" (may be marked as hidden or system)
3- open it with text editor like notepad
4- find line containing "**127.0.0.1   localhost**"
5- add new line below it containing "**127.0.0.1 www.google.com**"
6- save file and its done!
**Note:** replace www.google.com with every domain name that you like
**Note:** if you have problem in editing this file just boot your windows in **safe mode** and you will be able to edit and save it

**UPDATE**
if you are using Linux or Mac there is same way!
in linux edit this file **/etc/hosts**
in mac edit this file **/private/etc/hosts**

Comment: OP is using LAMP (L = Linux) and this just appears to be a way of disabling Google on a PC

Comment: Yes por changing the localhost I have that sorted out, it's the other thing I am more concern but thanks

Comment: @RiggsFolly there is same way in linux and mac , solution updated by hosts file in linux and mac

Comment: @dreid you can add multiple line like this:<br>
127.0.01 site1.test.com<br> 127.0.01 site2.test.com <br> And handle them by HTTP-HOST to create a relation between sub directory and defined domains :)

Comment: @Netlog this for example is not a solution for me, if I change my 127.0.0.1 to local.test.com the link in the browser is going to be http://local.test.com/test , I dont want the /test

Comment: another way is using hosts file +  htaccess file for url rewriting to handle this issue

Comment: @Netlog yes I will try to use the htaccess , thank you